# Screen script does not work

Tags: bash, screen, minecraft

I'm trying to use a script to start my Minecraft server on a detached screen. I have a `start.sh` file setup as per [instructions](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-installation/):

```
#!/bin/sh

screen -d -m -S minecraft java -Xms6G -Xmx6G -jar spigot-1.15.2.jar
```

After I execute `start.sh`, I check my screen list my Minecraft screen does not exist. If I cut out the screen bit the script works exactly as intended (screen also works just fine on its own). I'm not too experienced with bash, I may need an ELI5.

edit: some clarification

Comment: Is `screen` installed?

Comment: @user535733 Yes. I use it to run a few other scripts, but every time I have to manually create the screens and then detach. That's why I'd like to make a script to start the screen.

Comment: You made the script executable? You get NO error messages or warnings?

Comment: Yeah it's executable and runs just fine if its only the `java -Xms6G -Xmx6G -jar spigot-1.15.2.jar` bit.
If I include the screen part, it just does nothing. No error, no warning, no screen created.

Comment: Just figured something out. I was running the `start.sh` with `sudo` because the jar won't run otherwise. If I just run the script without `sudo`, the screen is created, but now the jar doesn't have permission to run. What's the workaround?

Comment: All I can think of is changing the entire directory's perms to a different group? They were all root by default but I suppose that's problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah so it was a permissions issue. The directory was owned by root:root just changed it to my user/group.